# Filter Json Array Data in Typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, filter, observable

I have recently started working on angular and I need to filter data from an JSON array.
Basically I want to display names whose id is less than 100. Below is not working for me.

```
list : any;

getOptionList(){
this.callingService.getData().pipe(
  filter((l) => l.id < 100)
).subscribe(
  (l) => { this.list = l;} 
)
}
}
```

Json Array from calling Service

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name": "B"
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.callingService.getData().subscribe((res: any) => {
      let filteredArr = res.filter(data => data.id < 100);
      //Here you got the filtered array.
});
```

It will work for you.

Comment: If this code works then please mark as right my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much tried it with another approach. Works!